# Problems with a PHP string

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm having some very odd and serious problems with a string...

For some reason, certain characters in a string are not passing through any functions correctly, and only in one PHP file (it works fine on other pages).

I had something working two days ago, but now there are problems.

For example, I have a string that looks like this:

```
http://example.com/v/asd238
```

I'm trying to change it to be something like this:

```
http://example.com/first/second/v/asd238
```

So I had this before:

```
preg_replace('/http\:\/\/example\.com\/([v|u]*)\/([a-z0-9]*)/i', 'http://example.com/first/second/v/$1/$2');
```

But for some reason the ':' and '.' make function basically do nothing. Even on functions like strpos() or str_replace().

I'm wondering why, if I even escape the two with '\', what is going on? I can't even remotely figure out why I'm having this problem.

Comment: So `str_replace('/v/', '/first/second/v/', $url)` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best way to do it:

```
str_replace('http://example.com/', 'http://example.com/first/second/', $url);
```

More on [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Well yes, but as I said, for some odd reason, the time that ':' is in the string, the function does nothing. For example, str_replace('http', 'ftp', $url) works, but not str_replace('http:', 'ftp:', $url)

Comment: @sackbot14 - Ties has an error in the way that `str_replace()` is called, but it works: http://codepad.org/0HnGGY9O (EDIT: Or at least the way that `count` is given: http://codepad.org/BVsSzqtn)

Comment: @sackbot14 - And here's your other comment-given example: http://codepad.org/CwdtVLzy

Comment: yeah i was reading the docs wrongly... my bad. the count parameter has to be a variable. this is because it is given the value of the number of replacements made.

Comment: I'll use the codepad site to show you the oddness of my problem: http://codepad.org/SAUKYPt7

Comment: I've just figured out that ':' was transformed into an HTML entity.... so searching for ':' returned no results -_-

Comment: @sackbot14 - See: http://codepad.org/hVwSXWf6 EDIT: HTML entity? What is the entity for a colon?

Comment: @sackbot14 - I'm not seeing an entity here for the colon: http://codepad.org/9nHeyW0L

Comment: I didn't know it was an entity, the string had gone through previous filters, one of them transformed various characters to entities, and I didn't know that.

Comment: @sackbot14 - Ok, so the real issue is that the data you're working with is not in the form you're anticipating, not that `str_replace()` isn't working? (Still would like to see "encoded" value, though.)

Comment: No, I've got it working. I just wasn't aware of what processes the string, I am modifying code and adding a feature, but I did not create it.